# Get the value index that is clicked in an archor in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have this nav-tabs of bootstrap,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!-- ko foreach:tabs -->
    <li><a data-bind="text: $data"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
 </ul>
```

I want that after the click, the index will be stored in the `this.tabIndex()`.
For example, ['Text','SMS','Call'],
Then if the user clicked to 'Call' tab, it will set the `this.tabIndex()` to 2.

How can I use click binding on this?

Here is my viewModel,

```
define(['knockout','jquery','underscore'], function(ko,$,_) {
return function appViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedTab = ko.observable(0);

    self.getTab = function(index){
        self.selectedTab(index);
        alert(self.selectedTab());
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Where is your `tabs` (observable?) array?  Your edit suggests that you're working at two entirely different levels of your viewmodel, so using `$parent` as per my answer won't get to the above object.

Comment: ah yes. i deleted the self.tabs = ko.observableArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `click` binding and wrapping the update to the `tabIndex` observable with an inline function, passing in the `$index` of the current item.

```js
var vm = {
  tabs: ['Text','SMS','Call'],
  tabIndex: ko.observable(0)
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach:tabs -->
    <li><a data-bind="text: $data, click: function() { $parent.tabIndex($index())}"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
 </ul>

Current tab: <span data-bind="text: tabIndex"></span>
```

---

Based on your comment:

> What if I have more to do in that function?

You could have your code look like this:

```
var vm = {
  tabs: ['Text','SMS','Call'],
  tabClicked: function(idx) {
    this.tabIndex(idx);
    //further work
  },
  tabIndex: ko.observable(0)
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<a data-bind="text: $data, click: function() { $parent.tabClicked($index()); }"></a>
```

Comment: What if I have more to do in that function? Can I use $parent.bind(function, param1, param2)? How?

Comment: You can swap it out for an entirely different function if necessary - create a function on your viewmodel at the same level as `tabIndex` that you pass the `$index()` parameter to, and have that update `tabIndex` using that parameter, along with doing any other work it needs to

Comment: can you provide sample? I cant understand your comment .

Comment: I've added a further example

Comment: There is no output. I tried to use alert in the function. alert is not showing. there is no error in the console.

Comment: What I've posted should work - indeed you can run the sample to see inline above.  You must have something else that's conflicting, or haven't quite implemented the above correctly, but with the information available here it's impossible to say.

Comment: I will edit the question, and I will show you how I code my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating new functions in your data-bind attribute (e.g. by `click: function() { console.log($index()); }` or `click: doSomething.bind($data, $index())`, I'd suggest using the actual `$data` as a reference.

The `click` binding already sends both the click event and the `$data` to its bound method. Here's what I mean:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.tabs = ["one", "two", "three"],
  this.selectedTab = ko.observable(this.tabs[0]);
  this.selectTab = function(data, event) {
      self.selectedTab(data);
  };
}


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: tabs">
    <li data-bind="click: $parent.selectTab, 
                   text: $data,
                   css: {
                     'active': $data === $parent.selectedTab()
                   }"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- example with a `with` binding -->
<div data-bind="with: selectedTab">
  <h1>Tab <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></h1>
</div>


<!-- example with a foreach + visible binding -->
<div data-bind="foreach: tabs">
  <div data-bind="visible: $data === $parent.selectedTab()">
    <h1>Tab <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because you're using a reference to the actual tab (which is a string in this example, but could be a whole viewmodel as well!), you can use it freely in other parts of the UI without having to look it up in an array.